# add together all of the labels in tableview cells

Tags: swift, uitableview, sum, addition

i want my swift code to add together all of the tableview cells together and convert it from a string to a int. The code should be called from the view did load func. The total should be 3 when all of the labels  are added together. Look at my comment in view did load for more info. The code does not use storyboards.

```
import UIKit
 
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
 
    var numberOfRows = 3
 
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { numberOfRows }
 
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { 118 }
 
    var tableView = UITableView()
    var selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 
        setTableVIew()
        
        //print the sum of the labels added togther on the tableview cells
        
    }
 
 
    func setTableVIew(){
    
          
         
       
        
        let VCframe = view.frame
        let height = VCframe.height * 0.8
           
        let widthx = VCframe.width
 
   
             tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: widthx - 20, height: height)
          
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        view.addSubview(tableView)
  
      
        tableView.register(customtv.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
 
 
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! customtv
       cell.lbl.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    
 
       return cell
   }
 
 
 
    
}
class customtv: UITableViewCell {
    lazy var backView : UIView = {
      let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 6, width: self.frame.width  , height: 110))
      view.backgroundColor = .green
      print(self.frame.width)
          return view
      }()
      
 
      
      override func layoutSubviews() {
         backView.clipsToBounds = true
         backView.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 6, width: bounds.maxX  , height: 110)
   
 
      }
    lazy var lbl : UILabel = {
        let press = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 3, width: 120 , height: 50))
        press.backgroundColor = .yellow
        press.text = String("1")
            
        return press
    }()
 
   
 
 
 
 
 
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(animated, animated: true)
        addSubview(backView)
    
        backView.addSubview(lbl)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get a solution yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you do this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setTableView()
    calculateSum()
}

func calculateSum() {

    var sum = 0
    for row in 0..<numberOfRows {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

        sum += Int(cell.label.text ?? "") ?? 0
    }
    print(sum)
}
```

Note: Make the class and object names consistent eg: `lbl` -> `label` and `customtv` -> `CustomTableViewCell` as I've given above. Even the method names `setTableVIew` -> `setTableView`. It would be best if you use [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint).

Comment: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. At let cell = tableview

Comment: You should update `customtv` in `cellForRow` method as `CustomTableViewCell`.

Comment: Tried what you said had no effect uploaded project to get hub if you want to look. https://github.com/redrock34/tableviewsum

Comment: Simply add `tableView.reloadData()` at the end of `setTableView` method.